# Unable to pass styles to quill-editor component in angular

Tags: angular, quill, property-binding

I'm trying to style a tag in `app.component.html` from `app.component.ts` but its not working.There are similar questions and articles but even the accepted answers ain't working for me. Here is my code.

`app.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row pt-5">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 bg-light">
      <form [formGroup]="editorForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="editor">
            <h3>Editor</h3>
          </label>
          <quill-editor [style]="editorStyle" [modules]="config" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my `app.component.ts` is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  editorForm: FormGroup;

  editorStyle = {
    height: '300px',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  }

  config = {
    toolbar: [
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['code-block']
    ]
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.editorForm = new FormGroup({
      'editor': new FormControl(null)
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('submit called');
    console.log(this.editorForm.get('editor').value);
  }
}
```

Things I tried:

`[style]="editorStyle"` //Not working

Then I tried doing it directly `[style.backgroundColor]="'red'"` with and without extra quotes aroud value `[style.backgroundColor]='red'`.

I also tried `[ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: 'red'}"` and `[ngStyle.backgroundColor]="'red'"'`. But nothing is working for me. The problem is only with `editorStyle` and not with `config`. I'm also getting this warning.

> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value [object Object] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

Comment: What is the code for quill-editor component? If you have host bindings in it, they can wipe out the attributes on the host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quill editor uses a custom `styles` field to pass down styling, so instead of

```
<quill-editor [style]="editorStyle" [modules]="config" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
```

You should specify

```
<quill-editor [styles]="editorStyle" [modules]="config" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
```

This is different to the styling a standard dom element

https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill

Comment: excellent sir. this worked. nobody told me that. I accept this answer

Comment: most welcome, yes an easy mistake to make for sure!

Comment: check https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/blob/master/src/quill-editor.component.ts for list of input and outputs of `ngx-quill`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have a problem of shadow Dom, which prevents styles to be applied to components under shadow dom. More detailed explain here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

Angular has its own way to handle shadow dom, and it's encapsulation
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Modify your app.component @Component annotation with this and give a try

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

This is not advisable as shadow dom is quite useful to keep control of your styles. And using 'None' encapsulation in your app.component can be risky so i think a better solution would be wrap your quill editor in a custom component who's only responsibility is to render the editor. This way, you are applying ViewEncapsulation.None only to this component.

Comment: No, it is not an issue of inheritance, the quill-editor component receives styles as a data input passed down (which doesn't seem to be working correctly)

Answer (score -1):

i try this for you :

you can edit there to correct your problems!

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbeepd)

Comment: thanks Saad. But `height` and `backgroundColor` attributes are not changing for my text editor. thats the problem.

Comment: see it again i do some modification